# How can I strictly infer const array index and value mappings?

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript code that I'm working on in order to get better, fully typed, enum-like structures.

```js
/** Basically any object, excluding number keys */
type EnumData = Record<string | symbol, any>;

/** A single entry in the enum */
type EnumEntry<TKey extends string, TData extends EnumData> = ({
    /**
     * Unwrap TData into the enum entry
     */
    [K in keyof TData]: TData[K];
}) & {
  /** Unique key/name of the enum entry */
  enumKey: TKey;
  /** Unique integer ordinal of the enum entry */
  enumOrdinal: number;
};


/** Type of a whole Enum "instance", including many entries */
type Enum<TKey extends string, TData extends EnumData> = Readonly<{
  /** Every enum entry */
  [K in TKey]: EnumEntry<K, TData>;
} & {
  /** Every enum entry indexed by its ordinal */
  [enumOrdinal: number]: EnumEntry<TKey, TData>;
}>;

/** An entry passed into `createEnum` that includes data */
type DataEntry<TKey extends string, TData extends EnumData> = {enumKey: TKey, enumOrdinal?: number} & TData;

/**
 * Create an Enum with the given entries
 * @param entries The enum entries
 * @returns The enum instance
 */
export function createEnum<TKey extends string>(...entries: TKey[]): Enum<TKey, {}>;
export function createEnum<TKey extends string, const TData extends EnumData>(...entries: ({enumKey: TKey} & TData)[]): Enum<TKey, TData>;
export function createEnum<TKey extends string, const TData extends EnumData>(...entries: ({enumKey: TKey, enumOrdinal: number} & TData)[]): Enum<TKey, TData>;
export function createEnum<TKey extends string, const TData extends EnumData>(...entries: {enumKey: TKey, enumOrdinal: number}[]): Enum<TKey, TData>;
export function createEnum<TKey extends string, const TData extends EnumData>(...entries: (TKey | DataEntry<TKey, TData>)[]): Enum<TKey, TData> {
  throw new Error("Unimplemented"); // pretend this is implemented
}
```

It is used in this manner:

```js
// String keys only
export const MySimpleEnum = createEnum('A', 'B');

// Custom enumeration
export const MyCustomEnum = createEnum({enumKey: 'A', enumOrdinal: -1}, {enumKey: 'B', enumOrdinal: 0});

// Attached data
export const MyDataEnum = createEnum({enumKey: 'A', hello: 'hello'}, {enumKey: 'B', goodbye: 'goodbye'});
```

I have one type issue left that I'd like to solve. Given this scenario:

```js
export const TestEnum = createEnum('ZERO', 'ONE');
export type TestEnum = EnumType<typeof TestEnum >
const testOrdinal = TestEnum.ZERO.enumOrdinal; // testOrdinal is type `number`
const testKey = TestEnum[0].enumKey; // testKey is type `'ZERO' | 'ONE'`
```

Please help me write a signature for createEnum such that `testOrdinal` is inferred as `0` and `testKey` is inferred as `'ZERO'`.

I've tried a bunch of things, (adding a new TOrdinal generic argument, adding both TOrdinal and TEntries that is type `Record<TOrdinal, TKey>` and propagating that down through everything, etc.) but can't seem to get it to work. I think I could do it pretty easily if I got rid of some of the `createEnum` overloads and forced the user to always specify `enumKey` and `enumOrdinal`, but I don't want to do that. I'd like to keep the string-only overload as well as the `enumOrdinal` defaulting to the array index.

Any ideas? I'm using TypeScript 5.3.

Comment: This code is considerably too large to be a [mre]. Please [edit] the code to just the absolute minimum needed to demonstrate the issue. If all you care about are typings, for example, you could remove the implementation entirely, and any apparent dependencies on third-party libraries like lodash. (also note that `key` is a type parameter, and should be written conventionally as `Key` or even better, `K`) Even if I do that, I get [this example](https://tsplay.dev/NB1g4w), which is *still* a bit larger than it should be for Stack Overflow. Could you please reduce it further?

Comment: Like, I can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpzyxw) to make your `TestEnum` case behave like an enum where you manually specify `0` and `1` for the ordinals.  That seems to answer the question *as asked*, assuming, as you say, everything would work if you forced the user to always specify `enumKey` and `enumOrdinal`... but you never get `"ZERO"` for `TestEnum[0].enumKey`, even in that case.  Either you have more problems with your code than you've asked about, or you are happy with `"ZERO" | "ONE"`. If you have more problems, you should split into a separate SO question. How can we proceed?

Comment: Sorry about the poor wording around the "works great" phrase. What I meant by "functionally" is "at runtime". I'll edit to fix that and I'll pare down the code. Ultimately, I want to keep the overloads, so that's an integral part of the question. Also, I don't think that this is two questions at all, since the `testOrdinal` and `testKey` cases are, as far as I can tell, two symptoms of the same problem. Gimme a few minutes to edit the question.

Comment: I didn't say anything about removing *overloads*.  But you *could* remove all those `enumWith`, `enumOrdinals`, for the sake of the question. That functionality and anything having to do with runtime is not really the part you're asking about, and all it does is add to the cognitive load of people who you're asking to help. My suggestion is you rewrite the question to be of the form: "please help me write a call signature for `createEnum` such that the following inputs give the following return types, and leave out anything except for the most basic stuff that currently isn't working for you."

Comment: ‍♂️ There's still stuff going on with intersections here that seem completely out of left field, I'm not sure what to do.  Seems that you could chop the whole thing down to a few lines.  Anyway, if I try to see past all that stuff and just build something that both gives you default `0`,`1`,`2`,... for string-only inputs *and* does the reverse mappings (which *is* two questions, it's two completely different pieces of functionality you need for one thing) I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3K2Em). But I'm loath to write this up as an answer because of the state of the question.

Comment: If you could please [edit] to fix this, make it conform to be a good SO question for future readers, maybe split it into two questions so you're asking only about either the auto-generation of `0`,`1`,`2`... *or* about the reverse mappings, I'd be more than happy to write up a full answer explaining.  If not, I think this question should probably be closed as needing more focus. Please let me know how you'd like to proceed here.

Comment: My guess as to why some stuff seems out of left field is because in the code as written now, I'm not sure what will and will not affect an answer by removing it. If I remove the TData stuff, does that fundamentally change things so that an answer will not be relevant to my actual use case? I don't know. If I ask about the enumeration and the key reverse mapping independently, will the answers I get for them work well together so I can get both? Probably not. It seems you have a much greater familiarity with this level of typescript than I do and so you see problems that I just cannot.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't supposed to be "please help me write an entire library where everything I want to work can work".  That kind of one-on-one ultra-specific help sounds like personal tech support, and is unlikely to be useful for future users. If you're posting questions here, you should try to give back to the community by making them helpful for others. - Did you look at [this potential solution](https://tsplay.dev/m3K2Em)? If it works for you, then we can decouple your specific issue from having a good SO question.  If it doesn't then what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how you can look at my original question and come away with the idea that I'm asking people to write a library for me. I appreciate your attempts to help, but if the bar to entry is to post a question that isn't relevant to my use case, or if I need to become an expert to understand how to ask the question in the first place, then I just won't post a question. Go ahead and close it.

Comment: I’m similarly not sure how you can look at my attempt to help and decide I’m asking to become an expert or ask questions irrelevant to your use case. It’s about making a [mre], which is almost by necessity not going to be directly targeted to your specific code, but rather a way to get you and future users across some particular hump you’re having trouble with.  Have you looked at my suggested solution? This is the third time I’ve asked, and I understand if you don’t want to deal with me anymore, but maybe that code would help you nonetheless?